# Removing almost-duplicates from nested list

Tags: c#, nested-lists

If I have the following sublists, how can I remove 'duplicates' so that I only have L1, L2 and L3 remaining? I don't mind which variant remains, as long as the duplicates are gone.

```
List<List<string>> mylist = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> L1 = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
List<string> L2 = new List<string> { "d", "e", "f" };
List<string> L3 = new List<string> { "g", "h", "i" };
List<string> L4 = new List<string> { "c", "a", "b" };
List<string> L5 = new List<string> { "a", "c", "b" };
List<string> L6 = new List<string> { "f", "d", "e" };
```

It's worth mentioning that I'm removing the duplicates to improve performance in another part of my program, so anything too intensive would not be appropriate. Thanks!

Comment: Well what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Linq by applying [**Distinct**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netcore-3.1) function with a custom comparer like the following code:

1 - Create Custom generic comparer for `List<T>`:

```
public class GenericComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<List<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<T> x, List<T> y)
    {
        return x.Count == y.Count && x.All(xx => y.Contains(xx));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<T> obj)
    {
        int hashCode = 0;

        foreach(T str in obj)
        {
            hashCode ^= str.GetHashCode();
        }

        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

2 - call Distinct function with `StringListComparer` like :

```
List<List<string>> mylist = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" },
    new List<string> { "d", "e", "f" },
    new List<string> { "g", "h", "i" },
    new List<string> { "c", "a", "b" },
    new List<string> { "a", "c", "b" },
    new List<string> { "f", "d", "e" },
};

var result = mylist.Distinct(new GenericComparer<string>()).ToList();
```

3 - Demo

```
foreach(List<string> strList in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", strList));
}
```

4- Result

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
```

If you have a list of integer, you can call `Distinct` method like :

```
var result1 = mylist1.Distinct(new GenericComparer<int>()).ToList();
```

I hope this help you out.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you.Out of interest - what would you have done differently if they were lists of integers instead of strings?

Comment: i updated my answer, by using generic comparer for string or int. can you upvote the answer please?